How to run Windows version of multi-platform image on a hybrid OS AKS cluster?
Configuration:

Cluster: AKS v1.27.9
Node pools:

UbuntuLinux, Standard_D8ads_v5
Windows2019, Standard_D8ads_v5


Argo Workflows v3.4.9 (not required)

This test pod fails with ErrImagePull:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: argoexec-multiplatform
spec:
  containers:
  - name: argoexec
    image: quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:latest
    command: ["powershell.exe", "-Command"]
    args: ["echo 'Hello from Argoexec on Multi-Platform'"]
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows

Even though the image is multi-platform and the pod is being scheduled on a Windows node.
However changing tag from latest to latest-windows causes the image to pull successfully.
For most cases, I would simply use latest-windows and move on. However Argo Workflows prefers a single tag for argoexec.
I assume I'm missing something obvious as I can't find posts from other users running into the same problem. Currently this issue prevents me from running the trivial hello-world examples in the docs.
Update 1:
The registry entry indicates a Windows version:

Running skopeo inspect docker://quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:latest returns:
{
    "Name": "quay.io/argoproj/argoexec",
    "Digest": "sha256:3842178f25616bbff4c7eafc95b48a2786da9a8369c1b34d2a1622717d0a706c",
    "RepoTags": [
        "2.0.0-alpha1",
        "2.8.2",
        "apiserverimpl",
        "auto-emptydir",
        "fix-2.12",
        "fix-4676",
        "fix-ttl",
        "inline-gc",
        "latest-linux",
        "multic-linux-amd64",
        "multic-linux-arm64",
        "multic-windows",
        "multic",
        "rm-server-linux-amd64",
        "rm-server-linux-arm64",
        "rm-server-windows",
        "rm-server",
        "test",
        "v2.0.0-alpha2",
        "v2.0.0-alpha3",
        "v2.0.0-beta1",
        "v2.0.0",
        "v2.1.0-alpha1",
        "v2.1.0-beta1",
        "v2.1.0-beta2",
        "v2.1.0",
        "v2.1.1",
        "v2.1.2",
        "v2.10.0-linux",
        "v2.10.0-rc1-linux",
        "v2.10.0-rc1-windows",
        "v2.10.0-rc1",
        "v2.10.0-rc2-linux",
....
        "sha256-66771d76c062590e9b0c04267838669d2d2503155f570ad7ba557fc72ffa7f77.sig",
        "sha256-d319c7337fdc94859dd9a92149daa69539982e833a0cbe97acc70de48fb4b474.sig",
        "sha256-aeb63c0db06468c650d48fd29879af9210e8ab7fb7e8a4317009b45ef95646fe.sig",
        "sha256-0931b0713abb021095c301bb73508a761192fcc6721ddcd516799eda541992be.sig",
        "v3.4.17-linux-amd64",
        "v3.4.17-linux-arm64",
        "v3.4.17-windows",
        "v3.4.17",
        "sha256-80a82145d4abd2e467b1151d98f55252e6f8c6eeae0ca58ef398e1b0090080a3.sig",
        "sha256-9bcc45a41df9c0b87aa2b581056c0baa6f9249250e86dcb2cd2245f9aef886b1.sig",
        "sha256-f0d2f739256f3ef079f2158fd04c8fb6584c8facf7fc727e8db866bb4b3d76c0.sig",
        "sha256-e518292c87a5c111a16bfc713116c81b289afa9720d953a22f5a5787d9bb1b56.sig",
        "sha256-ad69d62f44f8b8e7c3734b663032de14eaf405c493b170e0fecb22a3dc561ad5.sig",
        "sha256-54424f2390e3d0f9b7efe3d9c3650379a0c09a568ee9d96e6df6a392e7dcf071.sig",
        "sha256-17f2532714ffb8a6e2ee95a6b62ec7fe7e42b1a5a99ca2608228b9d835522105.sig",
        "sha256-4769496a9c4eda0ce49511bc471e6d191aeb13f1f2f19b63a2949b2fa75efe26.sig",
        "sha256-32bf73711d3e4326a0426a9ebf380249dc97a7646ad4d38e8e0d7d8450f5ad4e.sig",
        "sha256-70bf604413aeddc2b078c0e091424131f00104aac7904cd3086eeb0410733ef1.sig",
        "sha256-109dc4c486a16d0023f31ef5474fc00a3dd5cdb44e3dd6e725c989d9d39078cb.sig",
        "sha256-f048f0e248008733a986e8530bfb6d524ea5654719e1043ba055ae163bc3a183.sig",
        "sha256-3d7d20082b11c326a4514a05b4b9c36fa036c9a0c41b307a328fbf454d6dbdd4.sig",
        "sha256-30b75af4380273d9ae062a7cadd0cab78ef99a97db0401d45ae2233beef0bbba.sig",
        "sha256-d22ee52c78ed84919e4600d6ccb4ffd288928e02f6f62c9dae692c37d7aaeb97.sig",
        "sha256-cd9ec974c1a2bca0fc47c000bffc9604f36696cb0063ab0762b34cfe8fd4b2fe.sig",
        "sha256-9d2fa42e663879907b81e3ce2a0635dfc2c7476689d2e24d71f678ead76dfc3b.sig",
        "sha256-bc10f23ce4cce8ce1b100b2b678bf0102b3e2e1992a6f2b394e023572a1f3fd3.sig",
        "sha256-1699b73e9b3c863b3669674c1c318df6e401e8ff375124fd2655774be1fa471a.sig",
        "v3.5.7-linux-amd64",
        "v3.5.7-windows",
        "v3.5.7-linux-arm64",
        "v3.5.7",
        "sha256-1b8d22bec1cd2e33da260f63c1ece770db44c0b62ac2ee5522afc12d9de347bf.sig",
        "sha256-e1e691c94d94a26d1647765279b92932a4a5d0ca8cbc7bd02431aab8bbbb72a7.sig",
        "sha256-39ad87336f86fac326d85ab3aae28a9ce2ad088c7710a01d2fa401a6fb46f14b.sig",
        "sha256-587ba5154712468e5004ca3a6ccd332b1327776bed586e1230f4e4e879bc88b1.sig",
        "sha256-640b99bf6c990cc5ae3ad21bfa0d7a701e3adcab7f872679bca5731e8adb845a.sig",
        "sha256-e9939a91c1e2c8a2bd2ac1e00764def3c763ab5b8c03c14ec02377a5b3df1365.sig",
        "sha256-340eff9517714b8b8b2365192dc028baf67318cb17413f587e26aaa8173370fe.sig",
        "sha256-cca12f7d22015d5471f18fe24cc1d5dd103722f660fa28e8023b9eae51841b9a.sig",
        "latest-linux-amd64",
        "latest-windows",
        "latest-linux-arm64",
        "latest",
        "sha256-3842178f25616bbff4c7eafc95b48a2786da9a8369c1b34d2a1622717d0a706c.sig"
    ],
    "Created": "2024-06-02T04:36:59.652634915Z",
    "DockerVersion": "",
    "Labels": null,
    "Architecture": "amd64",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Layers": [
        "sha256:b2ce0e0660777651a7a188ae1128acc61d01aca10a035a8b1faa2cdd8bbf0785",
        "sha256:e8d9a567199d7a318c875f2558a679ba8a924f817afacbb428afc3ffe6be6828",
        "sha256:058cf3d8c2ba04ad7c064698c08c5e886a8623c0ad6171b8d72684253534417d",
        "sha256:b6824ed73363f94b3b2b44084c51c31bc32af77a96861d49e16f91e3ab6bed71",
        "sha256:7c12895b777bcaa8ccae0605b4de635b68fc32d60fa08f421dc3818bf55ee212",
        "sha256:33e068de264953dfdc9f9ada207e76b61159721fd64a4820b320d05133a55fb8",
        "sha256:5664b15f108bf9436ce3312090a767300800edbbfd4511aa1a6d64357024d5dd",
        "sha256:27be814a09ebd97fac6fb7b82d19f117185e90601009df3fbab6f442f85cd6b3",
        "sha256:4aa0ea1413d37a58615488592a0b827ea4b2e48fa5a77cf707d0e35f025e613f",
        "sha256:da7816fa955ea24533c388143c78804c28682eef99b4ee3723b548c70148bba6",
        "sha256:9aee425378d2c16cd44177dc54a274b312897f5860a8e78fdfda555a0d79dd71",
        "sha256:8e0a4320cff2b22fb7c1879723008623f26ff80de61a3854f3aed957a270f2e3",
        "sha256:5a4a298c3a9734bc731124f6418c5a1aa7c0449a047a0c5b81001754c3322c44",
        "sha256:4af13135566ff31b7be388b1c8100cb618f30f0af6becd127acc6b792cd450e4",
        "sha256:ffbc77996e549d15c23671ba43fb95c37b1497e83613642564bf310d009cd4ca"
    ],
    "LayersData": [
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:b2ce0e0660777651a7a188ae1128acc61d01aca10a035a8b1faa2cdd8bbf0785",
            "Size": 104180,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:e8d9a567199d7a318c875f2558a679ba8a924f817afacbb428afc3ffe6be6828",
            "Size": 13370,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:058cf3d8c2ba04ad7c064698c08c5e886a8623c0ad6171b8d72684253534417d",
            "Size": 537709,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:b6824ed73363f94b3b2b44084c51c31bc32af77a96861d49e16f91e3ab6bed71",
            "Size": 67,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:7c12895b777bcaa8ccae0605b4de635b68fc32d60fa08f421dc3818bf55ee212",
            "Size": 188,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:33e068de264953dfdc9f9ada207e76b61159721fd64a4820b320d05133a55fb8",
            "Size": 122,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:5664b15f108bf9436ce3312090a767300800edbbfd4511aa1a6d64357024d5dd",
            "Size": 168,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:27be814a09ebd97fac6fb7b82d19f117185e90601009df3fbab6f442f85cd6b3",
            "Size": 93,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:4aa0ea1413d37a58615488592a0b827ea4b2e48fa5a77cf707d0e35f025e613f",
            "Size": 385,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:da7816fa955ea24533c388143c78804c28682eef99b4ee3723b548c70148bba6",
            "Size": 321,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:9aee425378d2c16cd44177dc54a274b312897f5860a8e78fdfda555a0d79dd71",
            "Size": 130495,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:8e0a4320cff2b22fb7c1879723008623f26ff80de61a3854f3aed957a270f2e3",
            "Size": 52322569,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:5a4a298c3a9734bc731124f6418c5a1aa7c0449a047a0c5b81001754c3322c44",
            "Size": 20200,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:4af13135566ff31b7be388b1c8100cb618f30f0af6becd127acc6b792cd450e4",
            "Size": 2028,
            "Annotations": null
        },
        {
            "MIMEType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
            "Digest": "sha256:ffbc77996e549d15c23671ba43fb95c37b1497e83613642564bf310d009cd4ca",
            "Size": 160,
            "Annotations": null
        }
    ],
    "Env": [
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
        "SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
    ]
}

Update 2:
Per the comments, I tried setting imagePullPolicy and setting nodeAffinity via annotations:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: argoexec-multiplatform
spec:
  containers:
  - name: argoexec
    image: quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["powershell.exe", "-Command"]
    args: ["echo 'Hello from Argoexec on Multi-Platform'"]
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/os
            operator: In
            values:
            - windows

The same errImagePull still occurs.
About directly pulling the image on a Windows node, I don't think I have sufficient permissions on this cluster. Although I might find a cluster admin to try a hostProcess container. But even if it works, I would still need a way to ensure correct image pull without direct node access.

From the description of the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.

Does the image manifest includes the Windows version? what does skopeo inspect docker://quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:latest show?

Hmm. You mentioned that using the latest-windows tag works. Sometimes, explicitly setting the imagePullPolicy to Always can help or using node affinity with annotations might help. Try adding affinity and let me know. If the pod still fails to pull the image, directly Pull the Image on a Windows Node, give it a try once.

@Arko - Post updated with the latest attempt

Finally found the root cause thanks to a tip from MSFT. Examining the Windows node via kubectl shows:
Kernel Version: 10.0.17763.5696
Examining the quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:latest manifest:
os.version: 10.0.20348.2461
This mismatch in underlying Windows container OS was causing errImagePull.
By reverting to a sufficiently older version - quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:v3.4.8, image pulls start working.
My method of reverting argoexec versions - editing the image tag of the workflow-controller deployment:

Another option could be patching workflow-controller-configmap, but I wasn't successful implementing suggestions from other posts. The official docs are also unclear to me.
Lastly note it's still a mystery why I was able pull quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:latest-windows
¯\(ツ)/¯

On your last note about the mystery on why you were able to pull the earlier version, it might be the case that the latest is now being built for Windows Server 2022 and this version you were able to pull (3.4.8) was built on Windows Server 2019 base. Maybe a feedback to the Argo folks that they should build for both bases and provide tags for 2019 and 2022.

Completely agree! Also Win Server 2025 when it gets released later this year.
